# Get foreground window title using Haskell on Linux

Tags: linux, haskell, window, foreground

Under Windows, it is possible to get the foreground window title using: [getForegroundWindow](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.6.2.0/docs/Graphics-Win32-Window-ForegroundWindow.html#v:getForegroundWindow)

Is there an equivalent way to get foreground window title using Haskell on Linux? (preferably without using FFI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [X11](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11) library:

```
import Graphics.X11
import Graphics.X11.Xlib.Extras

main = do
  d <- openDisplay ""
  (w, _) <- getInputFocus d
  s <- fetchName d w
  print s
```